# Cannot zoom SVG in an HTML file

Tags: html, css, svg

I am writing a simple index.html page and containing only an SVG graph followed by a table. However, when I display the HTML, using command+Plus, I am unable to zoom the SVG (but I can zoom the table).

I have tried using `<img>`, `<object>`, and `<iframe>` as suggested [here](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/). Note that the width and height of the SVG are kind of big (they are both 3000).

```html
<body>
   <div class="main-wrapper">
     <img src="graph.svg" style="width:100%; height: auto">

     <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <th>value1</th>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>value2</th>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>value3</th>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

```css
.main-wrapper{
   height: 100vh;
   weight: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: `vh` and `vw` don't play nicely with zoom, unfortunately. Try using different units for your main wrapper. Also, any reason you're using `weight` instead of `width`?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the css code. It's supposed to be width: 100vw. However, it's still not working. I tried to add a container with bootstrap. `<div class="container><img...></div>` The layout is still not doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the css styling to the underlying svg instead of the `img` element:

```
img svg  {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
...
<img src="graph.svg">
...
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/3qwft5gL/) at jsfiddle (with another   svg, of course).

***Caveat***

The solution might depend on the structure of the referenced svg.